# How to fix a glitch where objects are replaced with simple green shapes?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I started a second playthrough on the campaign mode but found that:

- Every object and person was green
- All objects were replaced with simple shapes
- The cargo crate in the first mission was empty (it should hold dead bodies and flies)

I can guarantee this is not because of the television I use. It could be a glitch or a problem with a disc. I am using the Xbox 360 version. Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Is there any way I can fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an issue with corrupted data, so you might try deleting any title updates and re-downloading them.

- From the Xbox Dashboard, scroll to the right and find the "Settings" tab
- Press A on "System."
- Move down to "Storage"
- Select the entry for your Xbox's internal storage.
- Pick "Games and Apps" and then scroll down to the entry for Black Ops 2.
- In this menu, delete anything that has a yellow exclamation mark or anything that reads "Title Update."  Be sure NOT to delete your save game!

Then try running Black Ops 2, and you should be prompted to update the game.  After the update is done, see if the problem persists.

If you still have the problem, it's probably either the disc or your Xbox - if you can borrow or rent a copy of the game, try that, or take your disc to a friends' Xbox and see if it exhibits the same problem.

Comment: do you think resetting all of my data will make it work